# How can I use Emacs under Linux Mint as a proportional font Evil-mode editor and a proportional-font terminal?

Tags: fonts

In [OS X or X11 terminal emulator supporting proportional fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/563502/os-x-or-x11-terminal-emulator-supporting-proportional-fonts) Emacs is recommended for proportional font editing and shell use.

What can / should I put in a .emacs file so it loads Evil mode and displays text with a proportional font?

What should I put in a foo.el file so that calling Emacs with `-l foo.el` renders Emacs as a proportional font terminal?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to open Emacs, type `M-x customize-face` then type `default` when prompted for a face to edit. You’ll see a form that lets you choose a font as well as other details of the face such as size, weight, and color. Save the buffer with C-x C-s and the new settings will both take effect immediately and be saved to your init file so that they are permanent.

Comment: And `M-x ansi-term` to use as a terminal.